# Add line break to the secondary title in a wordpress Post

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a line break to the secondary title on the Posts.

This code works perfectly fine for the title, but not for the sub-title. Do you know how to apply a `<br>` to the secondary title ?

```
<h3>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php echo str_replace(' <br> ', '<br />', the_title()); ?>
  </a>
</h3>
<p>
  <?php echo str_replace(' <br> ', '<br />', get_secondary_title()); ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Do you have a "<br>" inside the secondary title?

Comment: @Flo Yes, I do have a <br>. This is what I have in the secondary title section: second sample <br> title.

Comment: maybe your "<br>" is saved encoded like "&lt;br&gt;" Can you check that?

Comment: The HTML out is this: <span class="secondary-title">second | title</span>   . Even if I replace the <br> with another symbol like this  | , it still does not add the next line

Comment: @Flo it is encoded like you said, here is the HTML : <span class="secondary-title">second &lt;br&gt; Title</span>

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

**Simply insert the following shortcode code into your child theme functions.php file**

```html
/* ------- Line Break Shortcode --------*/
function line_break_shortcode() {
 return '<br />';
}
add_shortcode( 'br', 'line_break_shortcode' );
```

its work!

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. Can you please please elaborate?

Comment: @Priyanka Modi if i added that code to the functions.php, what code do I need to add to the home.php (where I echo the secondary title) ?

Comment: @PriyankaModi. User wants to  display encoded `br` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the htmlchars back like that:

```
<?php echo str_replace(' <br> ', '<br />', htmlspecialchars_decode(get_secondary_title())); ?>
```

Comment: That looks like it would work, but I tried it and it still gives me the same output :     `<span class="secondary-title">second   &lt;br&gt;  Title</span>`                                          
  I also tried this `<?php str_replace(' <br> ', '<br>', the_secondary_title());?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(the_secondary_title());?>`

Comment: Maybe you can do something like that: 
<?php echo str_replace(' &lt;br&gt; ', '<br />', get_secondary_title()); ?>